# VBA prevent empty cells/data in sheet or array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having some trouble to wrap my head around an array problem.
I collect data from a sheet and stores it into an array. xData(0) will be completed and can not miss data. But xData(1) there the values are stored may miss a value so I want to replace the empty cell with a 0. Instead of using `for loops` to add 0 into the sheets I'm thinking of using an array, due to the reason that I cant find a way to add 0 directly to the sheet without decreasing the speed. I have around 10 sheets in 15 different workbooks and therefor I need to find a faster way to do this.

My code snippet is as following.

```
Dim xData(1) As Variant

'Collect the data from the sheets ()
xData(0) = xData(1) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2)
xData(1) = xData(1) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Value2)
```

This will produce a 2D array but the xData(1) will not be the same size as xData(0) if any cell is empty (missing data). Is there a way to change the size of xData(1) to fit the size of xData(0), and then add 0 to the remaining length.  Is there any other way because this may cause problems later on too because of the case if 1 value is missing in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to replace empties with zeros, here is the core of an approach that:

- avoids loops
- avoids VBA arrays

Say we have data in column **A** from **A1** through **A1000** with some empties in that range.  Running:

```
Sub ChangeEmpty2Zero()
    Dim rng As Range, rngE As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A1000")

    On Error Resume Next
        Set rngE = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngE Is Nothing Then rngE = 0
End Sub
```

will fill those empties with zeros.

**NOTE:**

If the "bottom of the column is outside `UsedRange`, that "bottom" will not be changed.
You could adapt this to run on whatever ranges in whatever worksheets you need.

Comment: I really like the solution instead of using a loop. But I'm a bit confused how it add the zero to the sheet?

Comment: @Fredrik The first part of the code creates a range that includes all the empties in the range of interest.  The second part of the code *(the last line)* sets **all** the cells in `rngE` to zero.  It can do this in "one shot" rather than loop..............try it on a new test worksheet.

Comment: it works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help! :)